# Pseudocode Latex

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

How to write this algorithm pseudocode in latex:

```
Algorithm 1  Channel Assignment using Random Ordering (RO)
    K←Set of channels
    C(v)←0,∀v∈V
    root← Root Selection(V)
    C(root)← Channel Selection(root,K)  
    Permutate(V\\{root})
    while  (V!=Empty)
                  v← Removehead(V)
                  C(v)←Channel Selection (v,K) 
         V←V−1
    end while
    Return(C)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Welcome! Add a MWE, please.

Comment: Googling for "latex algorithm" yields [Wikibooks: LaTeX/Algorithms](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms), among other tutorials. This seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation of an algorithm in pseudocode using [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,longend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  $K \gets \text{Set of channels}$\;
  $C(v) \gets 0,\forall v \in V$\;
  $\text{root} \gets \text{Root Selection}(V)$\;
  $C(\text{root}) \gets \text{Channel Selection}(\text{root},K)$\;
  $\text{Permutate}(V,\text{root})$\;
  \While{$V \neq \emptyset$}
  {
    $v \gets \text{Removehead}(V)$\;
    $C(v) \gets \text{Channel Selection}(v,K)$\;
    $V \gets V-1$\;
  }
  \KwRet{$C$}\;
  \caption{Channel Assignment using Random Ordering (RO)}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]